# personalizar correo de bienvenida enviado desde php

Tags: php, html

Buenas,

No encuentro la forma de personalizar un mensaje de bienvenida que se envíe después de registrarte en la web. Veo que tampoco hace caso a las etiquetas de HTML.

Estoy usando:

```
$destinatario = $mail;
$contenido = "<br>Bienvenido a la web</br>,

Necesitas validar el correo para poder utilizar todas las características de la web e iniciar sesión.";

mail($destinatario,"",$contenido);
```

El mail se envía pero en texto plano y los acentos no me los coge, me sale por ejemplo `sesiÃ³n.` en vez de sesión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) indica claramente que **para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera `Content-type: text/html;`**.

Y, si quieres mandar HTML se recomienda construir un documento HTML con al menos los elementos básicos del mismo (etiquetas `<html>, <head>, <body>` ... tanto de apertura como de cierre.

Este código ejemplo es el mismo del Manual. Si tienes problemas con los acentos, puedes indicar: `charset=UTF-8` en vez de: `charset=iso-8859-1`.

```
<?php
// Varios destinatarios
$para  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // atención a la coma
$para .= 'wez@example.com';

// título
$título = 'Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto';

// mensaje
$mensaje = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>¡Estos son los cumpleaños para Agosto!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Quien</th><th>Día</th><th>Mes</th><th>Año</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3</td><td>Agosto</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17</td><td>Agosto</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Cabeceras adicionales
$cabeceras .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <cumples@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Enviarlo
mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Una vez más, justo lo que buscaba y no encontraba.

Comment: @JetLagFox Me alegro de que te haya servido.